# How to create an association between two models with form choice field using Active Admin, Paperclip in Rails 5.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, paperclip, activeadmin

### **Scenario**

I am building a similar App like AirBnB but the difference is that only the Admin can add new Apartments, Rooms, Houses etc. Therefore I created an Admin Panel with the activeadmin gem. I am now adding the image upload system into activeadmin so I am using the paperclip gem. I have two models "room" and "photo". The photo model has an "image" column. The room model has an "listing_name" column.

**room.rb (app/models)**

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :photos
end
```

**photo.rb (app/models)**

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

If I am not putting a custom form inside "photo.rb (app/admin)" I can associate the image to a room by default. But I can't upload a picture! This looks like this:

[image]

So I changed the "photo.rb (app/admin)" file into this:

**photo.rb (app/admin)**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Photo do
   permit_params :image

   form :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
      f.inputs "Project Details" do
          f.input :image, :required => false, :as => :file
      end
      f.actions
   end

   show do |ad|
      attributes_table do
         row :image do
            image_tag(ad.image.url(:thumb))
         end
      end
   end
end
```

With this form I can upload a picture into the image column but I can't associate it to a room and the edit view does not give me a preview of a picture as the show view does:

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Questions:

1. **How can I have a preview of the image in the admin edit view?**
2. **How can build a form to associate an image to a room by choosing the    listing_name of the room?**

Something like this:

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I suggest you to upload image on the room edit/create form rather than adding separately and linking you can use nested_attributes_for to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

**photo.rb**

```
...
   show do |image|
      attributes_table do
         row :image do
            photo.image? ? image_tag(photo.image.url, height: '100') : content_tag(:span, "No photo yet")
         end
         row :room_id do
            photo.room ? photo.room.listing_name : ""
         end
      end
      active_admin_comments
   end

    form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
      f.inputs do
         f.input :image, hint: f.photo.image? ? image_tag(f.photo.image.url, height: '100') : content_tag(:span, "Upload JPG/PNG/GIF image")
      end
      f.inputs do
        f.collection_select :room_id, Room.all,:id,:listing_name
      end
      f.actions
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/599 and then Macfanatics answer. It describes setting up a polymorphic association and how to use this within activeadmin. It has helped me a lot.